# How to concat two javascript variables and regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex, concatenation

I want to be able to concat two variables with a regular expression in the middle.

e.g.

```
var t1 = "Test1"
var t2 = "Test2"
var re = new RegEx(t1 + "/.*/" + t2);
```

So the result I want is an expression that matches this..

```
"Test1  this works   Test2"
```

How do I get a result where I am able to match any text that has Test1 and Test2 on the ends?

Comment: What are the `/` around `.*` for?

Comment: Write the regex, then write JS Code to build that. don't just start slapping variables and operators around without a clear idea of what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (I use [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs)):

```
> var t1 = "Test1"
> var t2 = "Test2"
> var re = new RegExp('^' + t1 + '.*' + t2 + '$')
> re
/^Test1.*Test2$/
> re.test("Test1  this works   Test2")
true
```

#### Note

- `.*` as stated in comments, this means *any character* repeated from 0 to ~
- the *slashes* are automagically added when calling the `RegExp` constructor, but you can't have nested unprotected *slashes* delimiters
- to ensure `Test1` is at the beginning, i put `^` *anchor*, and for `Test2` at the end, I added `$` *anchor*
- the *regex* constructor is not `ReGex` but `RegExp` (note the trailing `p`)

Comment: `.` does not match any character in JS regex patterns.

Comment: For a "dot-all" in JS, some people use `[\s\S]*` or `[^]*`

Comment: `.*` is what's OP try to do, and is what I want to do to it's his needs

Comment: Won't work. Try `'Test1Test2Test3'` (shouldn't match, but will...)

Comment: you should enforce the beginning of the string with `^` otherwise you'll get wrong `true` , ex:`hi Test1Test2`

Comment: Now it's simply fragile.. what if `t1='start*'; t2='end...';`? Obviously `Test1/2` is just placeholders. RegExp is the **wrong** tool for this task.

Answer (score 2):

The RegExp constructor takes care of adding the forward slashes for you.

```
var t1 = "Test1";
var t2 = "Test2";
var re = new RegExp(t1 + ".*" + t2);

re.test("Test1 some_text Test2"); // true
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex:

```js
var t1 = 'Test1';
var t2 = 'Test2';
var test = function(s) { return s.startsWith(t1) && s.endsWith(t2); };

console.log(test('Test1  this works   Test2'));
console.log(test('Test1 this does not'));
```

Answer (score 1):

if you know the beginning and the end you can enforce that:

```
var re = new RegExp("^" + t1 + ".*" + t2 + "$");
```

Answer (score 0):

Take care that the value of the two variables do not contain any special regex characters, or transform those values to escape any special regex characters.

Of course, also make sure that the regex in between matches what you want it to :-)